# Change of fluid of Pump

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pumps

If the fluid moved by a pump is changed by another different one, what will be the effect of such kind of operation for the pump ? 
Specifically, a pump moving 60 m3/hr of "liquid nr. 1" (sp.grav.: 0.800 / visc.: 0.65) should now move  53.5 m3/hr of "liquid nr. 1" + 6,5 m3/hr of    "liquid nr. 2" with sp. grav. 0.56 and a viscosity of 0.17. 
Is there a way to locate to operation point of the pump on the performance curves delivered py the manufaturer and has somebody experience with a situation like this ? Considering that the viscosity as well as the specific gravity of the mixture will be lower than at the previous operating point, what problems could occcure ? (cavitation, erosion, motor overload etc. )

Kind regards,
Marcus

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: ok, I will try this

Comment: Do the two fluids mix well together, or are they immiscible, like water & oil? Also, for how long would the pump need to move the combined fluids compared to moving the main fluid, fluid Nr 1? I have seen pumps move clear or dirty water & then move oily water for a short time & then move dirty water with no apparent immediate detriment in performance of the pump.

Comment: The two fluids mix well together, they are already mixed downstream of the pumps, now the intention is to mix them upstream. This is a mid-term solution until we upgrade the unit and install new pumps. It could last 2-4 years.

Comment: We are talking about turbopumps? If so, look here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22031/pump-power-and-fluid-viscosity/22042#22042 ... Or you do employ the time-honored engineering method: pick up the phone, talk to the supplier of your pumps.

Comment: What viscosity (kinematic/dynamic), units?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to my library at the moment but the link can give you some information : https://neutrium.net/equipment/pump-power-calculation/

Comment: That is a comment. Shame Solar Mike Shame.

Answer (score 0):

This is used to move dirty water in ponds. The cover is used to screen out anything that would jam the pump but it is also used to mix the particles evenly with the water on slower velocity pumps.

[image]

Ideally in those gold mining high velocity it is a pump

[image]

if it the rock will pass the hose it will not jam the pump and the high velocity keeps better but cost more. I would like to see what kind of pump you are using now.